# Trouble parsing some text from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to scrape some text out of a webpage. The text I wanna scrape generates upon filling in an inputbox. My script can fill in in the right way and can populate the value. However, it can't parse the text. How can I do it?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://dev.delshlearning.com.au/test.php")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#AM"))).send_keys("`(2(3^5-sqrt(3)))/2`",Keys.RETURN)

item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#MQ"))).text
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

The `send_keys()` parameter is already filled in within the script for your consideration.

Comment: what do you mean you can't? like there's an error?

Comment: It neither parses the text nor throws any error. I could not find the text in the source code or even by inspecting elements but it is visible in that site.

Comment: How is it not there when you inspect the elements?

Comment: This is the first time I'm experiencing such issues, It's kinda weird but I mean it. The link is attached within the script. See for yourself what I told you about,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is storing the **text** values in the attribute `value`. This should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://dev.delshlearning.com.au/test.php")

# I changed your locater to ID since it's a little more clear
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"AM"))).send_keys("`(2(3^5-sqrt(3)))/2`",Keys.RETURN)
item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"MQ"))).get_attribute('value')
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

I found it by going to the element's ***properties*** as shown highlighted here:
[image]